# Could / Should answer flagged as "Not an answer" be rescued

Tags: discussion, flags, answers

Sometimes valid answers are flagged because they include additional questions at their end.

Is it permissible or desirable to save them by removing the questions or would that be an invalid edit.
(In case the OT is reachable I could leave a comment.)

Another case would be a high votet, accepted answer which would not be an answer as it stands
, but together with the additional comment(s) of the of the responding user would be  a valid answer.

Is it permissible or desirable here, to included the comments into the answer?

In case of that should/could be done, would flagging with "invalid flags" be correct or improper?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it permissible or desirable to save them by removing the questions

Yes, it certainly is.

> Is it permissible or desirable here, to included the comments into the answer?

Yes, it certainly is.

> In case of that should/could be done, would flagging with "invalid flags" be correct or improper?

Flagging as Other and explaining that you have fixed the deficiencies is another option, though "invalid" makes the case just as clearly, so long as *all* issues in the answer are fixed.

Comment: Regarding the second case, I've accepted a few suggested edits doing that, however other reviewers rejected them as "radical change". Am I then allowed to do the edit myself, or would that be considered unethical?

Comment: @Stijn - it really depends on the scope of the change. When it comes to **code**, most of the time reviewers will reject. The edit summary should contain something to the line of "important information in the comments rolled into post" - that helps reviewers understand where a large change may have come from.